# Camera direction and `view_frame()` - How to calculate the direction vectors that describe the corners of the camera frame

Tags: python, camera

The camera origin is:

```
scene = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]
camera_origin = scene.camera.location
```

The camera direction is calculated with

```
camera_direction = scene.camera.matrix_world.to_quaternion() @ Vector((0.0,0.0,-1.0))
```

The `view_frame` i.e. *camera_corners* are:

```
camera_corners = scene.camera.data.view_frame(scene=scene)  # camera corners
```

At this point `camera_corners` contains 4 vectors.

**Question:**
From the `camera_origin`, how do I calculate the direction of the `view_frame`/`camera_corners` similar to the `camera_direction`?

Comment: See links I posted in previous question re using these.  The `view_frame` method gives local coords of camera bounds.  Convert to global just as have with camera -Z axis.